# Simple rustic DIY bunk bed, but is the plan safe?

Tags: carpentry, wooden-furniture

I plan to build a bunk bed for a tiny cabin, used on occasional remote outings. I've slept in ones like this so I know what I am getting into, but I want to make sure my plan is not too rickety. I would like the top bunk to be able to reliably support 250-300lbs in case two small adults sleep up there (unlikely, but good to over-engineer for safety).

What I'm planning is bunk beds made of plywood platforms 78" long and 42" wide, with the uprights extending 72" tall to accommodate top bunk and a safety rail. There are two approaches I am considering, based on sturdy wood shelving designs and bunks like this I've used.

## Plan A - Length-wise rails

[image: bunk plan A with length-wise rails]

## Plan B - Width-wise rails, more standard for garage shelving

[image: bunk plan B with width-wise rails]

Here is a screenshot from a video showing the plan B approach but on a shelf with less depth and more platforms. This shows how the platforms are supported with 2x4"s sistered to the full-height posts.
[image: screenshot of shelf build video]

In both plans, there are upright posts at the corners of the frame, then there is a continuous line of wood connected (like sistered studs) to those posts, made up of small sections of vertical 2x4"s, width-wise 2x4"s, and length-wise 2x4"s. My thinking is the weight of people or objects on the platforms will press down into the 2x4"s, so it is wood itself holding things up, rather than screws. The screws just hold it all in place and help weight transfer to the right spots.

**Is plan A, using length-wise rails, sturdy enough to support around 300lbs (a person or two small people sleeping on it)? If length-wise rails are not the way to go, why not? I see a lot of garage shelves use the approach in plan B with width-wise rails under the platforms - is my plan B sturdy enough, or what needs to be added to help it support ~300lbs?**

Comment: A drawing (plan) would be easier to grasp than trying to figure out exactly what you intend from your text description. My first pass at parsing your text description leaves me thinking you are proposing some poorly designed screw-joints. 2x4's properly joined should be plenty strong (walls made of 2x4's hold up houses) but poor joint design can make a weak structure that's prone to failure. You may also need some braces to keep it from racking.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I added a drawing. Dimensions aren't perfect (drawing shows bunk ~6' long, it will be more like 6.5'). What about the screw-joints I described makes you think they are poor? I include a zoom in on the important joinery I am thinking of. I want to make sure the screws I use are appropriate and I apply them in the right directions, but I am trying to avoid joinery that requires extra tools as this will be built in a remote setting (with battery drill & driver, screws and/or nails and hammer, lumber on site, could get bolts and other hardware if needed).

Comment: Braces meaning 2x4s at a 45 degree angle to connect the bottom of the top-long rail to the nearest upright? That makes sense, better than a small metal L-bracket.

Comment: If there is any way you could put a notch into the posts that the rails would land in, that would go a long way to supporting the rails. Given your location/lack of resources, I'd suggest what isherwood suggested in other posts: to make the notch, set a circular saw for a shallow cut (may 3/8"?), mark the edges of where the notch will be and make multiple cuts, knock out the pieces, clean up with a chisel. Making a notch puts the weight on the wood of the post, rather than the screws if there was no notch.

Comment: I updated this post to have shelf designs depicted in videos. I wonder if that shelf setup is sufficiently sturdy to use as a rustic platform to cap out on, in terms of wood joinery and weight support given the width and length of the platforms? I want each platform (just a top and bottom 'bunk' not a full set of shelves) to hold at least 300# safely.

Comment: You still need to draw up a plan for _your_ use, then share that plan with us for review. Videos go missing on a daily basis, so there's no telling if those will even be there tomorrow or a year from now when someone else has a similar question.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I have removed video links and added pictures instead, including my own specific plans and a more specific question.